# How to resolve AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_create_row_inbound_converter'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running into an unusual case where running this snippet of code in spark-submit fails, but works as intended when running the pyspark shell ('pyspark')

This is the code snippet:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sc = SparkContext('yarn-client', 'pyspark')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sqlContext.registerFunction("stringLengthString", lambda x: len(x), IntegerType())
sqlContext.sql("SELECT stringLengthString('test')").collect()
```

The error that I get is:

```
File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 418, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_create_row_inbound_converter' on <module 'pyspark.sql.types' from '/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py'>
```

Any recommendations on how to address the failure?

Full trace:

```
16/01/14 19:59:31 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.0.0.9): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 139, in load_stream
    yield self._read_with_length(stream)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 418, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_create_row_inbound_converter' on <module 'pyspark.sql.types' from '/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py'>

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:398)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/01/14 19:59:36 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azureuser/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT stringLengthString('test')").collect()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 280, in collect
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.0.0.9): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 139, in load_stream
    yield self._read_with_length(stream)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 418, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_create_row_inbound_converter' on <module 'pyspark.sql.types' from '/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py'>

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:398)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(DataFrame.scala:1778)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1778)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1778)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collectToPython(DataFrame.scala:1777)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 139, in load_stream
    yield self._read_with_length(stream)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 418, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_create_row_inbound_converter' on <module 'pyspark.sql.types' from '/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py'>

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:398)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BatchPythonEvaluation$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(python.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: is there full error trace available?

Comment: Updated the post with the trace

Comment: Okay it could be a bug in the library, more i cannot tell from the source code yet. But I noticed the `from pyspark.sql.types import *` line. I had this once in a program that I had a file named "types.py" and I did the `from types import *` thing. This lead to a weird behavior and I received exceptions deep from other libraries I was using. Just as an idea you may change the import line to something like `from pyspark.sql import types as foo_types*`. Just as a try...

Comment: I removed that entire line and the IntegerType() as it's no longer required in Spark 1.6 - still getting the same error

Comment: What is your python version? Maybe the lib requires another python version... It looks like the thing happens deep inside. Since you are using a snippet from the original docs one should expect that it runs proper.

Comment: Python 3.4.3 - and it runs just fine in pyspark shell, it doesn't using spark-submit